An early 2000's action movie set in wilderness
Genre: Action, martial arts
Language: English (US, 95% sure)
Movie seen in between: 2000 - 2004
Aired on: Star Movies (India)
Characters description:
Three characters who play major roles in the movie.

Lead male - Young, early 20's, average height, blond (90% sure) with slight curls and good looking.
Lead female - Young, early 20's, average height, slim, straight hair, brunette (99% sure) and good looking.
Lead female's brother - early 30's, muscular, broad shoulders, trimmed hair and definitely having beard.

Storyline and Scenes I remember: Our guy (lead male) starts off his journey (don't remember his purpose) on foot and comes across a village mostly bad guys and anarchy. There he meets the lady (lead female) and her brother. Good guys living in the village are so vulnerable and defenseless. Since the guy is good at martial arts he starts teaching to the good guys. With in a short time, as expected, the guy and the lady starts liking each other.
I don't remember what happens in the middle but I remember a few scenes.
Intermediate Scene: Where all of the village starts celebrating for something with loud music and djs and alcohol, that's when our guy and the lady slips off the crowd and goes to a lonely place and starts making out and as usual some other person interrupts and threatens them that their relationship will be told to the lady's brother.
Climax scene:
This scene is entirely shot in fort of some kind. The lady's brother is shirtless and someone shoots him from behind on his shoulder and he falls on to the ground instantly. And after sometime, someone falls from the top of the fort on to the steps in front of the fort and I think the guy dies.
The lady villain, my memory is strong in remembering her, She is in a pair of tiny tight shorts and a top with her abdomen exposed, long dark hair and I think she's good at sword fighting. Someone thrusts a big sword through the back of her stomach and we could see that the sword is visible from both front and back of her stomach (I remember this scene clearly because I also watched the making of the movie on the channel.).
These are the details I remember.

Very well written.

@ CGCampbell Thanks for the encouragement. I really appreciate it.

@ downvoter May I know the reason for downvoting? Is there anything I could do to make the question look better?

Hmm, this sounds so much like a Chinese martial arts film, you sure it was a US production? Were the actors American too?

@ Tivep I'm sure it's not Chinese and the actors are also not Chinese. The lead guy somewhat reminds me of the guy from "The forbidden kingdom".

But the leads in The Forbidden Kingdom are Jackie Chan and Jet Li, both are Chinese. Which guy from The Forbidden Kingdom are you referring to?

Are you referring to Michael Angarano? The kid in the movie?

It's the kid in 20's I'm talking about.

@chaitanya89 The downvote was most likely by someone who simply thinks ALL identify-this questions should be disallowed. (I once thought that. Now that they are expressly allowed, I no longer blanket down-vote, unless there is not enough information to go on.) Your question appears to have plenty of information.

This sounds almost exactly like the 2005 martial arts movie The Challenge (AKA Kampfansage - Der letzte Schüler). In it, our blonde hero arrives on foot to a derelict city and meets a pretty Asian brunette and her bearded vigilante brother, then helps the locals in their fight against an evil team of brother and sister, and the sister (Kleo) is sexy, has long hair and wears revealing clothes. The only problem is that the film is German, but according to an IMDb review:

I came across this German film in Star Movies (it was dubbed in English).

Here's the trailer:




While writing the question, I some how knew that no matter how vague my description was, guys in this site would nail it. This is exactly the movie I'm looking for. Thank you so very much.

@ Walt How funny, I thought it's the beard guy who was shot on the shoulder but from the trailer, it turns out it's the hero himself.

It happens. :) (Didn't want to mention it just in case it happens to beardo too.) Glad you found it.
